# Настройка библиотек для CMake (Windows)

Tags: c++, c, windows, cmake

У меня такая проблема, что я не могу настроить cmake для данного [проекта](https://github.com/butor/blackbird). Я так понимаю по сообщению:

```
Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find Jansson (missing: JANSSON_LIBRARIES JANSSON_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find SQLITE3 (missing: SQLITE3_LIBRARY SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

у меня проблема с подключением библиотек (SQLITE3, OPENSSL, CRL, JANSSON). В CMakeList.txt ничего не менял и вообще пока в данном проекте ничего не менял. Помогите мне настроить Cmake так, чтобы он находил библиотеки. В Cmake до этого никогда не работал и поэтом вообще без понятия как там все это делается.

Comment: Посмотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763224/Как-находить-библиотеки-с-помощью-cmake/763327#763327)

Comment: @ixSci Я не очень понимаю как могу его связать с решением.

Comment: @PoulShipilov там написано, как заставить cmake искать нужные библиотеки.

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n Я просто тупой, не могу все равно понять как мне их установить. Я вроде и скачал то, что нужно. Мне кажется, что делаю неправильно, когда сами библиотеки скачиваю. Что вообще с ними делать, вот я скачал архив допустим CURL - разархивировал, а потом что? Что делать с этой папкой с исходниками библиотеки?

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2013/)

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n Я видел эту сслыку много раз, но я говорю, что до этого Cmake не видел ни разу и поэтому не могу понять, что именно от меня требуется. Если вам не сложно и вы так много знаете про CMake, можете пожалуйста написать для меня конкретный алгоритм действия, для моего проекта, в ответе, что-то на подобии "Перетащить этот файл туда и т.д.". Еще раз повторю, что буду очень благодарен вам за это.

Comment: @PoulShipilov добавьте в текст вопроса текущий код cmakelists.txt

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n Я ссылку на github добавил

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n так мне стоит ждать вашей помощи?

Comment: @PoulShipilov `set(SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR extern/sqlite3)`
`set(SQLITE3_LIBRARY extern/sqlite3)` -- пример (ДО find_library). Недостающие части скачать, указать в cmakelists так же пути до header-ов, собрать части и указать пути до библиотек

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы CMake нашел необходимые библиотеки, их необходимо скачать, собрать и установить, согласно документации на каждую из них. После этого необходимо задать дополнительные параметры для CMkake, которые требуются для той или иной библиотеки. Посмотреть, какие параметры требуются можно в конкретном скрипте поиска (обычно пишут в комментариях в шапке скрипта). Скрипты лежат в <путь где установлен CMake>\CMake\share\cmake-<версия>\Modules. Скрипты поиска библиотек - Find*.cmake. Если скрипта для какой-то из библиотек нет, то его необходимо написать самостоятельно, используя документацию CMake.