# Как подключить библиотеку к проекту СМаке и с++?

Tags: c++, cmake

Всем привет.
Пишу приложение для андроид. Для работы нужна низкоуровневая библиотека для подключения к БД MySQL.
Итак, скачал исходники коннектора с официального сайта и не совсем понял, как с ними работать дальше. В арсенале Ubuntu 16.04 + QtCreator + CMake.
Пока забудем про Андроид и попробуем написать простое консольное приложение, которое выполняет один запрос к БД и просто печатает результат.
Надо сначала собирать коннектор или подключать в СМаке как библиотеку с исходниками? 
Если я собираю статическую библтотеку (`libmysqlcppconn-static.a`) и подключаю в Смаке так:

```
set(MYSQL_DIR /home/mark/apps/cppdev/next_mysql_proj/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.9/driver/)
add_library(mysql STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET mysql PROPERTY
    IMPORTED_LOCATION ${MYSQL_DIR}libmysqlcppconn-static.a)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} mysql)
```

Возникает вопрос, а как его включить в код на с++, то есть где взять заголовочные файлы?
В папке с полученной статической библиотекой много таких, 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

однако, с ними программа не компилируется и выдает ошибки в исходных файлах коннектора, которые, как я понимаю, уже не нужны, потому что мы используем не исходники, а скомпилированную библиотеку. *Как их заставить ссылаться на нашу скомпилированную библиотеку?* Чую, что надо какие-то флаги проставить, но мы же указали в Смаке путь к библиотеке.

Прилагаю код приложения (main.cpp) на всякий случай:
В инклудах, увы полная ерунда

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include "mysql_driver.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>


#define EXAMPLE_HOST "localhost"
#define EXAMPLE_USER "little_pig"
#define EXAMPLE_PASS "little_pig"
#define EXAMPLE_DB   "little_pig"


using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    string url(argc >= 2 ? argv[1] : EXAMPLE_HOST);
    const string user(argc >= 3 ? argv[2] : EXAMPLE_USER);
    const string pass(argc >= 4 ? argv[3] : EXAMPLE_PASS);
    const string database(argc >= 5 ? argv[4] : EXAMPLE_DB);

    cout << "Connector/C++ tutorial framework..." << endl;
    cout << endl;

    sql::Driver* driver;
    sql::Connection* conn;
    sql::Statement* stmt;
    sql::ResultSet* result;

    try
    {
        driver = sql::mysql::get_driver_instance();
        conn = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", EXAMPLE_USER, EXAMPLE_PASS);

        stmt = conn->createStatement();
        result = stmt->executeQuery("use little_pig; SELECT question FROM little_pig.littlepigmodel where id = 1;");
        while (result->next())
        {
            cout << result->getString(1) << endl;
        }
        conn->close();

        delete conn;
        delete stmt;
        delete result;
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException &e)
    {
        cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
        /* what() (derived from std::runtime_error) fetches error message */
        cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;

        delete conn;
        delete stmt;
        delete result;

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    cout << "Done." << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

P.S. А может быть надо динамическую библиотеку собирать и использовать?.. Но вопросы те же...

Comment: Посмотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/763327/15146)

Answer (score 0):

После двух дней страданий, я всё же частично осилил проблему.
Собрать и запустить свой минипроект удалось пока только с использованием динамической библиотеки. Для использования статической, надо пофантазировать с взаимным расположением файлов .о и .а.
Я могу в чем-то ошибаться, поправьте, пожалуйста.
Итак, что я понял. Никаких дефолтных путей поиска библиотек и хэдеров изначально нет. Именно поэтому при компиляции в консоли мы должны компилятору явно указать пути поиска хэдэров и библиотеки. Грубо это выглядит так:
`g++ /my/dir/libfoo.so -I<папка с .h>`
`g++ -L<папка с .so> -I<папка с .h>`
Если мы используем СМаке, то моём случае, это выглядит так:

```
set(MYSQL_DIR /home/mark/apps/cppdev/next_mysql_proj/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.9/driver/)
set(MYSQL_INCL /home/mark/apps/cppdev/next_mysql_proj/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.9/)
add_library(mysql SHARED IMPORTED)
# Указываем путь к файлу библиотеки
set_property(TARGET mysql PROPERTY
    IMPORTED_LOCATION ${MYSQL_DIR}libmysqlcppconn.so)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} mysql)
# Указываем путь к заголовочным файлам
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${MYSQL_INCL})
```

В файле main.cpp инклуды я написал так:

```
#include "driver/mysql_connection.h" // В кавычках пишутся пути относительно текущего файла
#include "driver/mysql_driver.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>          // В угловых скобках, относительно 
#include <cppconn/exception.h>       // target_include_directories, который
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>       // определен в скрипте СМаке
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
```

Теперь надо разобраться со статической библиотекой. Цель была именно такая.

Comment: Для статической библиотеки вам нужно ещё и Qt собрать статически. + Я сам пытался собрать коннекторы версий 2.* до 1.4. В итоге собралась только новая версия 8.0.5, что есть плохо (Новый синтаксис и тд). Release Md и Release My собирались почти без проблем, а вот для debug все плохо.

Comment: @MrBin пожалуй, нет. Я просто учусь собирать библиотеки. Эту, в частности, я планирую потом собрать для Андроида ( а UI там нарисую стандартными средствами). А вот со статическими Curl и Boost мне посидеть придется. MySQL требует их наличия.